# how to Delete file form folder by php..by name which is written by user in html form (input)

Tags: php, html

how to Delete file form folder by php..by name which is written by user in html form (input).Please help to do this thanks..

```
unlink();
```

Comment: SO is not a coding service.

Comment: Imho. It ud be the worst possible thing to allow an attacker to try, if you get my point..

Answer (score 1):

I'ts different than files:

Fom http://php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php

```
<?php
if (!is_dir('examples')) {
     mkdir('examples');
}

rmdir('examples');
?>
```

You'll likely want to pull a $_POST variable to, so:

```
<?php
$folder = $_POST['folder'];
if (!is_dir($folder)) {
     rmdir($folder);
}
?>
```